# HTML ALIGNMENT ISSUE - Internet Explorer

Tags: html, jsp

I have a jsp for searching and listing the projects. I have a field for indicator. Whenever the value of indicator becomes 'Y', a database will be called and the projects will be listed. In my case, I am getting all projects. But there is an issue in alignment.

In Mozila and Chrome, there is no issue in alignment. When I tried it in IE, i get the list as shown below.

May I know why it misbehaves in IE?

[image]

Comment: Because IE is....just wrong. If anyone uses IE then slap them in the face.

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code for replicating your issue.. Thanks